# can a struct assignment overlap similar to memmove() or is struct assignment like memcpy()?

Tags: c, standards

There are two different functions for making a copy of a data area in the Standard C library, `memmove()` used for overlapping memory areas and `memcpy()` for disjoint, non-overlapping memory areas.

What does the C standards say about struct assignment as in:

```
struct thing myThing = {0};
struct thing *pmyThing = &myThing;

myThing = *pmyThing;     // assign myThing to itself through a pointer dereference.
```

Does the struct assignment follow the rules for `memmove()` or for `memcpy()` or its own rules so far as overlapping memory areas are concerned?

Comment: It is the same statement like `x = x`.

Comment: Or more precisely, it's like `myThing = myThing;`

Comment: @Osiris Not really. This assignment might be implemented as `memcpy`, which is restricted to non-overlapping buffers. So the question is interesting. Yet I do not believe there is a restriction imposed by the standard on the assignment, so any complying compiler will not use `memcpy` in such a case.

Comment: Struct self-assignment follows the same rules as any other self-assignment.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Then the compiler would be required to use `memmove` if it cannot prove that the memory regions don't overlap (and if they don't, then it could use `memcpy`). The OP's code *is* like `x = x`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Then one could also argue that `x = x` may be implemented as `memcpy`. I think in this case the compiler is not allowed to use `memcpy` when he can not ensure that the elements do not overlap.

Comment: Now I see that this question is a little more interesting. If you write `x = x` the compiler can tell immediately that they're the same variables, and can just optimize the assignment away completely (unless it's volatile). But with `x = *ptr;` it usually won't be able to tell whether they're the same or not.

Comment: @Cornstalks Well, yes. Semantically they are alike.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Then what's the point of your "Not really." comment?

Comment: Isn't struct assignment defined to be equivalent to memberwise assignment?

Comment: @Cornstalks Because the OP seem to understand that. He is interested of internals I guess

Comment: It can implement it any way it likes, as long as the result matches the specification.  I don't think there's anything in the spec that prohibits `x = *ptr;` where `ptr == &x;`.

Comment: Well, there is *something* in http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16.1p3 - *If the value being stored in an object is read from another object that overlaps in any way the storage of the first object, then the overlap shall be exact and the two objects shall have qualified or unqualified versions of a compatible type; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.*

Comment: @Cornstalks Here is a compiler that uses `memcpy` without checking if the objects are the same or not: https://godbolt.org/z/v5f9vE - So should I file a bug against gcc? Or better modify `memcpy` upstream to zero out the overlap and wait for funny things to happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Section 6.5.16.1 ("Simple assignment") of the C standard (reading from draft N1548) states:

> In *simple assignment* (`=`), the value of the right operand is converted to the type of the assignment expression and replaces the value stored in the object designated by the left operand.
>
> If the value being stored in an object is read from another object that overlaps in any way the storage of the first object, then the overlap shall be exact and the two objects shall have qualified or unqualified versions of a compatible type; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

The C standard doesn't specify *how* the compiler implements the simple assignment. But overlap between the source and destination are permitted if the overlap is exact and the types are compatible. Self-assignment (whether through a pointer or not) meets this requirement, and thus the behavior is well-defined.

Comment: What is the meaning of "overlap is exact"? Going through some code I found a pointer to a global was passed to a function which then assigned the dereferenced pointer back to the global memory area as in `ItemCommonLocal = *pDataBuffer;` where `pDataBuffer` is a pointer to `ItemCommonLocal` and it suddenly struck me since it was overlapping, was there a problem.

Comment: Exact overlap means they start and end on exact same boundaries. Or simply the same object.

Comment: Here is a compiler that uses `memcpy` for this, no matter if it is the same object or not: https://godbolt.org/z/nPxqWc - But that is undefined behaviour, because for `memcpy` " The memory areas must not overlap." (quoting from the man page). So is the compiler wrong here? Or does it somehow know that `memcpy` does the right thing (like doing nothing if the pointers are the same)?